# CSS: 2 DIVs, one takes a fixed size, other one fills up the remaining space

Tags: html, css

I have 2 DIVs, one containing a map, this one is above the other one. It should take all space available, except for the footer, which is 25px high.

Currently I give the map 95% of the height, and the footer 25px. Problem is when the windows gets really big, the footer becomes enormousness, and when the windows becomes really small, scroll bars kick in.

However, this is not what I want, I want:

```
#map { height: <window_height - footer_height> }
#footer { height: 25px }
```

How could I achieve this using only CSS and HTML?

PS. I know there probably are some simple javascript solutions, but for educations sake, I want to know how to do this without javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this:
[keeping footers at the bottom of the page](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page)

All the code is there.
Basically you do this in your HTML:

```
<html><body>
<div id="container">
   <div id="map"></div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

And then in your CSS:

```
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#map {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:25px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:25px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
```

There are other ways to achieve this and similar effects.
Let know if this is what you wanted.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. The map I'm using is Google maps, and it will be only 10px high when I use this code.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to embed the map? Are you using standard Google Maps iframe solution?

Comment: I fixed it using javascript, still looking for the CSS solution though. Here's the link: http://zanzibar.idlesoft.net/geomap/