# CSS layout that fills available space

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to do a seemingly simple webpage layout, but I'm hitting a wall.

I'd *like* to do everything **purely with CSS** (**no tables** to muck things up, and **no javascript** dynamically resizing things)

I'd like to have:

- A heading with a fixed height
- A footer with a fixed height
- Left sidebar with a fixed width
- Right sidebar with a fixed width
- The whole layout always fills the entire viewport (i.e. if the user resizes the window, the layout grows to the new size)

Put another way:

```
|<                Total width is 100% of viewport             >|

+--------------------------------------------------------------+  ---
|                 Header with a fixed height                   |   ^
|--------+-------------------------------------------+---------+    
|        |                                           |         |    
|        |                                           |         |    
|  Left  |                                           |  Right  | Total
|  with  |        Center grows in height/width       |  with   | height
|  fixed |      and has scrollbars if necessary      |  fixed  | is
|  width |                                           |  width  | 100%
|        |                                           |         | of
|        |                                           |         | viewport
|        |                                           |         |  
|--------+-------------------------------------------+---------|   
|                 Footer with a fixed height                   |   v
+--------------------------------------------------------------+  ---
```

The parts that are giving me the most trouble are

- Having the sidebars and center have a height equal to the height of the viewport minus the heights of the header and footer
- Having the center have a width equal to the width of the viewport minus the widths of the two sidebars

**I have no problem requiring users to have a modern browser.**

I'm aware that similar questions to this have been asked before, such as

- Make a div fill remaining space (`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717564`)
- Three row tableless CSS layout with middle row that fills remaining space (`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703455`)
- Create 2 divs, one takes up remaining space (`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717564`)

... and the conclusion seems to be that there isn't a good solution.  Those answers are somewhat old, so I'm hoping that someone knows the trick now.

---

Yes, I'm aware that this appears to be trivial to accomplish using a `<table>`, and after "banging my head against the wall" I did actually attempt to achieve the layout using a table.  Unfortunately, with this approach, I have been unable to get the center section to show scroll bars (using `overflow: auto`) when the content grows too large.)

Comment: You can't do this in a cross-browser way without using tables. Tables can do this trivially. You will spend a lot of time bashing your head against a wall. Tables are a tool and if "pure" CSS can't do what you want (which it can't in this case) you need to get over it and use tools that can.

Comment: @cletus: Regarding "Tables can do this trivially" ... can it also allow the scrollbars part for the center area?  I actually did attempt to do the whole thing with tables, and it almost worked, except for the scrolling part (only chrome seemed to respect `overflow: auto` when used inside a `td`)

Comment: Doing this is relatively simple with CSS, cross browser, and you don't need tables. I'll try and put a link together with a sample of the markup but I'm going out of town Monday night for a week so don't know if I'll be able to do that by then.

Comment: @Rob: Thanks; this *feels* like it shouldn't be that painful.

Comment: @Rob the big problem is the center area taking up the rest of the available space so 100% minus the fixed elements. This has *always* been a problem with divs. You only really have hacky solution where the center is 100% high and the other elements overlay it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

how about [THIS](http://www.petercarrero.com/tableless-table.html)?
it works with konqueror (KHTML), chrome (webkit) and firefox (gecko). like anything recent, it will probably barf under IE6.

```
    <html><body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <div style="position: absolute; background: #faa; 
                height: 100px; top: 0px; width: 100%;">header</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; background: #afa; 
                top: 100px; bottom: 100px; left: 0; width: 100px;">left</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; background: #afa; 
                top: 100px; bottom: 100px; right: 0; width: 100px;">right</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; background: #faa; 
                height: 100px; bottom: 0px; width: 100%;">footer</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; background: #aaf; 
                bottom:100px; left: 100px;top: 100px;right: 100px; overflow: auto;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tincidunt tempor
 velit quis volutpat. Nulla pharetra pulvinar arcu sed lacinia. Nulla ultrices aliquet sem, 
vitae commodo elit condimentum ut. Nulla consectetur facilisis nibh, et tempus purus 
pellentesque nec. Ut eu nibh ut arcu mattis luctus. Cras at interdum quam. Pellentesque 
imperdiet mi vitae felis sollicitudin iaculis. Maecenas accumsan tortor neque, at posuere 
felis. Quisque ultricies mi quis dolor pellentesque elementum. Maecenas quis nunc tortor. 
Cras eu velit faucibus nulla volutpat mollis. Aliquam fermentum lobortis diam ut pharetra. 
Duis mattis posuere fringilla. Morbi consectetur mauris vel libero pellentesque varius. 
Aenean leo enim, placerat a feugiat nec, ultrices et nulla. Etiam tincidunt urna id justo 
molestie faucibus. Cras neque enim, semper et sodales eu, volutpat nec urna. Vestibulum 
interdum arcu et ante egestas ut lacinia dui semper. Cras ligula lacus, aliquet nec dapibus 
ac, commodo vitae libero. In gravida venenatis sapien a convallis.</p>


    <p>Nulla ac risus eu velit pulvinar pretium. Etiam porttitor viverra sollicitudin. 
Donec lectus mi, posuere quis luctus facilisis, lacinia non ante. Sed sed mi neque. Etiam 
neque risus, bibendum et tincidunt vel, pharetra nec risus. In hac habitasse platea 
dictumst. Nam sollicitudin condimentum lorem, quis dignissim turpis sagittis nec. 
Pellentesque diam nunc, rhoncus quis lobortis id, lacinia quis lorem. Maecenas tempor metus 
nec velit facilisis in rhoncus lectus varius. Integer mollis, odio ut pharetra varius, elit 
nulla pellentesque neque, a egestas est justo dapibus neque. Vivamus a mauris massa, sit 
amet commodo orci. Aliquam nec iaculis sapien. Suspendisse ornare, tortor eget mattis 
tempus, nulla ligula fermentum elit, vitae euismod odio metus ac risus. Etiam iaculis 
dignissim consectetur. Nunc molestie lorem ac neque pulvinar vitae eleifend justo 
facilisis.</p>

    <p>Duis a sem turpis, et cursus arcu. Suspendisse potenti. Sed eu risus orci, eget 
bibendum justo. Praesent dapibus porttitor mauris, ac sollicitudin eros pretium quis. 
Curabitur mi eros, aliquam et ultrices et, adipiscing ut mauris. Nunc pretium malesuada nisi 
laoreet consectetur. Phasellus mi arcu, rutrum in blandit in, consectetur non risus. 
Vestibulum enim lacus, aliquam eu ultrices a, tempor ut turpis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur rhoncus faucibus sapien, quis vulputate eros tempus 
consequat. Vivamus id metus massa. Vivamus aliquet enim quis sem viverra eu molestie elit 
cursus.</p>

    <p>Mauris at lorem massa. Aliquam risus ligula, vestibulum et placerat condimentum, 
pellentesque sit amet justo. Cras tempor sollicitudin ultrices. Aliquam sed elit sapien. 
Praesent consectetur molestie vehicula. Pellentesque quis lectus et nunc accumsan feugiat. 
Ut rhoncus aliquet libero sed rhoncus. Fusce egestas nunc eu elit vestibulum placerat. Class 
aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. 
Phasellus vitae nisi ante, id fermentum justo.</p>

    <p>Donec iaculis magna nec elit fringilla imperdiet. Proin mauris sem, pellentesque sed 
ultrices ac, luctus ac elit. Donec blandit, orci ac volutpat luctus, turpis sem malesuada 
tellus, eget porta magna nisi vitae quam. In vitae scelerisque urna. Proin ante odio, 
ultrices lobortis scelerisque at, dictum non justo. Pellentesque tincidunt congue leo 
malesuada ullamcorper. Quisque dapibus, massa dignissim gravida blandit, augue felis 
vehicula urna, et ullamcorper turpis orci sit amet nibh. Ut vitae consequat nibh. 
Pellentesque turpis justo, ultrices ac porta in, pretium quis quam. Donec purus nisi, 
dignissim vitae hendrerit vel, hendrerit ac sapien. Fusce facilisis purus a libero elementum 
ultrices. Nunc in libero congue ipsum tempor suscipit. Pellentesque pharetra pretium 
volutpat. Nam sapien arcu, viverra vitae euismod sit amet, mollis nec arcu. Phasellus at 
elit metus, sit amet tempus turpis. Phasellus mattis justo ut est varius facilisis ut et 
leo. Phasellus congue cursus est eget luctus. In eleifend diam at enim ultricies a lacinia 
mauris molestie. Nunc porttitor bibendum vulputate. Pellentesque quis risus vel mi 
pellentesque imperdiet vitae ac nunc.</p>

    </div>
    </body></html>
```

Comment: Ohh, good one! The thought of absolute positioning for setting the size of an element crossed by mind while I was writing mine, but I didn't think of it as a solution to the problem at hand - very nice!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a bit of a strange thing to try to do. Nevertheless, I took a shot at it, and I may have only gotten as far as you got, but maybe I used a different method that could be useful. I'm very interested to see if Rob has a better way. My method works, with one problem: the content is scrollable, but you can't see the scroll bars. I can't seem to think of a way to fix this. Anyway, here's what I came up with:
http://www.happyspork.com/layout_test.html

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's interested I developed a layout that uses `css` to emulate dynamic `table` behaviour [using `div`s]. It works in Chrome, Firefox and IE>7.

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/qJ48W/show/light/), have a go at resizing the window

As it stands all five components grow as their respective contents do, however, if you really want your left and right sides fixed just apply a `width` rule to `.east` and `.west`.

Have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qJ48W/) with it.

**Code:**

```html
<div class="view" style="height:100%; width:100%">
    <div class="north">
        n
    </div>

    <div class="middle">
        <div class="west">
            w
        </div>

        <div class="centre">
            c
        </div>

        <div class="east">
            e
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="south">
        s
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
html, body {
    height : 100%;
    margin : 0;
}

.view,
.view > .middle {
    display : table;
}

.view > .north,
.view > .south {
    height : 1px;
    display : table-row;
}
.view > .north { vertical-align : top; }
.view > .south { vertical-align : bottom; }

.view > .middle > div {
    display : table-cell;
}
.view > .west,
.view > .east {
    width : 1px;
}

/*div { border : 1px solid black; }*/
```

Simple markup, no JS, and dynamic layout. Uncomment the `border` css line to see whats going on.
At the bottom of your question I see you tried using tables but with issues. Placing a `max-height` on `centre` or `middle` might be what you want (for the scrollbar thing). Maybe this can help you.