# How to expand CSS column to available space?

Tags: css, sass, css-float, compass-sass

[There is a way to do it using absolute positioning.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535186/css-layout-that-fills-available-space)

I have a two-column layout. The left column is a fixed 200px width plus 30px left margin. The right column contains the content and should expand to fit the available space.

I have done it by positioning each column using absolute positions and stretching the right column using right: 0px to that it will touch the right edge. Is there a way to achieve the same effect when using float:left to define the columns? So far the column is only expanding to fit the width of its contents.

Bonus points if I can do this using Compass/Sass (but I don't want to rely on frameworks like Blueprint, since the layout is pretty trivial).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Art; you have to write like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="left">left fix width</div>
<div class="right">right no fix width</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left{float:left;width:200px;margin-right:30px}
.right{overflow:hidden}
```

check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/4RN2j/

Comment: I think this is exactly what he's after.

Comment: thanks thirtydot; that trick i am learn from you :). check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056759/two-divs-the-same-line-one-dynamic-width-one-fixed/6057049#6057049

Comment: This doesn't work if you are trying to vertically center your row elements, but that's an issue for a different thread.